# subquery in query contains query element linq not working

Tags: c#, linq

Greetings Everyone 
I have two Linq queries as follow

```
var sub_query = from x in db.table
where 
     x.item1 == "abcd"
select new
{ 
   x.Item2 //is a string
}

var query = from y in db2.table
            where
                 sub_query.ToList().Contains(new {y.item2}) //error here 
            select new { y.element }
```

This is not working  
It doesn't recognize anything from y & throws the anonymous error 
`y.item2` is a string 
I also tried directly `sub_query.Contains`inside`query` but same error 
**Edit (error given)**

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(AnonymousType#1)'
>   has some invalid arguments

**PS :** when i Build the solution the error disappears & if for example remove the comma (;) & put a new one the error comes back

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous objects you are creating aren't actually equal. See the following code:

```
string myString = "foo";
string myOtherString = "foo";

var x = new { myString };
var y = new { myOtherString };
```

x.Equals(y) will return false, and so will your call to Contains.

It should work if you select the string directly instead of wrapping it in an anonymous object. For example:

```
select x.Item2
```

and

```
sub_query.ToList().Contains(y.item2)
```

Comment: it worked but i don't get it. if they are the same type & let's say same value why wouldn't it work?

Comment: The implementation of .Equals() for anonymous types uses == instead of .Equals() on all of its internal objects (reference equality, not value equality, for strings). In my example, myString == myOtherString returns false, but myString.Equals(myOtherString) returns true. Anonymous types use the == comparison inside their .Equals() method.